# ARM programming output an array and malloc to clear input array?

Tags: c, assembly, malloc, arm

My assignment is to take an array of numbers and put it into ARM assembly and perform 2's complement, and then output it again for display. I was able to do most of the work but the output tells me it is not working right.

C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int * comp( int a[], int size ) ;

void main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
int array[] = { 1, -1, 252, -252, 0, 3015 } ;
int size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(int) ;
int * result ;
int i ;

result = comp( array, size ) ;
printf( "Original Complement\n" ) ;
for( i = 0 ; i < size ; i++ )
printf( "%d %d\n", array[i], *(result+i) ) ;

}
```

ARM assembly:

```
AREA |comp$code|, CODE, READONLY ; tell the assembler stuff

IMPORT malloc ; import malloc to be used

EXPORT comp ; tell the assembler to show this label to the linker

comp ; the label defining the entry point

stmfd sp!, {v1-v6, lr} ; standard entry
str v1, [a1] ; copy a1 over to v1
str v2, [a2] ; copy a1 over to v1
bl malloc ; clears pointer for new array

loop
ldr a4,[v1],#4 ; start going through loop starting at top or array
mvn a4, a4 ; ones complement
add a4,a4,#1 ; make it 2's complement

str a4,[a1], #4 ; move back into the array
subs v2, v2, #1 ; set a flag for the end of the loop
bne loop ; start again for the next value in the array
ldmfd sp!, {v1-v6, pc} ; puts all registers back into the caller
END
```

output:

```
Original  Complement
0         -442500552
-1        -442500552
252       0
-252      0
0         0
3015      0
```

can anyone help me figure out why its giving me such a messed up output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
str v1, [a1] ; copy a1 over to v1
```

That will store the undefined contents of register `v1` over the first element of the int-array passed in `a1`. You can see that the first element in the original array in your output has been overwritten with `0`.

If you mean to remember the original `a1` in another register, you probably meant `mov v1, a1`.

```
str v2, [a2] ; copy a1 over to v1
```

Again not what you meant, but with `a2` being the small integer `size` I'm surprised this attempt to write to low memory doesn't immediately crash!

```
bl malloc ; clears pointer for new array
```

You're not passing in the amount of memory you want to `malloc` here, it's getting the int-array address and treating it as a number of bytes. Assuming 32-bit `int`, you would want to `mov a1, a2, asl#2` to multiply the int size by 4 bytes.

You should probably also check that it hasn't failed and returned `NULL`.

```
ldmfd sp!, {v1-v6, pc} ; puts all registers back into the caller
```

The result register `a1` will be pointing to the end of its array at this point instead of the start. You'll want to store the original result of `malloc` and return it here.

Comment: I didnt have any difference of an output doing the changes you selected, but i thank you for your response.